# I'm trying to find a element in an array that not repeat

Tags: php

i have to do a function to find a number that not repeat in an array.
It's simple but i have no idea for where begins.

```
function $returnUnique($arr) {
   
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple, you need `array_filter` and `array_count_values`:

```
$result = array_filter(array_count_values($array), function ($count)
{
    return $count === 1;
});
```

`$result` will contain all unique elements from your initial array.

Comment: That needs `array_keys` around it.

Comment: You are right, `array_keys` should be used to receive a clean result.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_search(1, array_count_values($arr))
```

will find an element (specifically, the first element) that is only found once in the array.